# Why this simple Tensorflow code is not successful? (ConvnetJS using Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow

There is an simple and educational toy classifier (2 fully connected layers) as JAVA applet: http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/demo/classify2d.html

Here, input is a list of 2D pts with {0,1} labels. As you can see there, they define the architecture as below.

```
layer_defs = [];
layer_defs.push({type:'input', out_sx:1, out_sy:1, out_depth:2});
layer_defs.push({type:'fc', num_neurons:6, activation: 'tanh'});
layer_defs.push({type:'fc', num_neurons:2, activation: 'tanh'});
layer_defs.push({type:'softmax', num_classes:2});
```

I am trying to test this using tensorflow as below.

```
pts = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,2], name="p")
label = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None], name="labels")

with tf.variable_scope("layers") as scope:
    fc1 = fc_layer(pts, [2, 6], "fc1")
    fc1 = tf.nn.tanh(fc1)
    fc2 = fc_layer(fc1, [6, 2], "fc2")
    fc2 = tf.nn.tanh(fc2)
cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(fc2, label, name='cross_entropy_per_example')
cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy, name='cross_entropy')
optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate, 0.9)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy_mean, global_step=global_step)
```

and the function`fc_layer` is nothing but

```
def fc_layer(bottom, weight_shape, name):
    W = tf.get_variable(name+'W', shape=weight_shape, dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(mean = 0.01,stddev=0.01))
    b = tf.get_variable(name+'b', shape=[weight_shape[1]], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(mean = 0.01,stddev=0.01))
    fc = tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(bottom, W), b)
    return fc
```

However, loss seems not decreasing. Is something wrong about loss definition (cross entropy)?

Could anyone can help?

Comment: You seem to feed inputs in batch, yet the `label` is rank 1 only. Does your model get labels?

Comment: Yes. For example, `P`=[[-0.2443358,   0.04343621], [-0.45233325,  0.27792488],  [0.21115686, -0.02241944]], and `L`=[1, 1, 0], which are feed into `pts` and `label`

Comment: I see now, sorry: I did not know that this form is a requirement for `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`, as explained in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/nn.html#sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having a closer look, it seems to me there is no problem with the loss definition.

---

I have found some parameter definitions differ from the original [ConvNetJS demo](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/demo/classify2d.html). Choosing the same parameters did not change the behaviour, though.

Then I realized that the ConvNetJS page does not explain how weights are initialized (couldn't find in the source after a quick search, and the code sample here is hidden in the text area :-P). And that is one issue that really changes the behaviour.

Another parameter that influences the results has been the batch size.

#### Before (mean=0.01, dev=0.01)

[image: Original weights (mean=0.01, dev=0.01)]

#### After (mean=0, dev=1/n), n number of inputs to the layer

[image: New weights (mean=0, dev=1/n)]

The code that generates the second image (replace the weights to the original values to get the first one), on learning to recognize when two input numbers have the same sign:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import random

# Training data
points = [[random.uniform(-1, 1), random.uniform(-1, 1)] for _ in range(1000000)]
labels = [1 if x * y > 0.0 else 0 for (x, y) in points]

batch_size = 100 # a divider of len(points) to keep things simple
momentum = 0.9
global_step=tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(0.01, global_step, 10, 0.99, staircase=True)

###
### The original code, where `momentum` is now a variable,
###   and the weights are initialized differently.
###
def fc_layer(bottom, weight_shape, name):
    W = tf.get_variable(name+'W', shape=weight_shape, dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=0., stddev=(1/weight_shape[0])))
    b = tf.get_variable(name+'b', shape=[weight_shape[1]], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=0., stddev=(1/weight_shape[0])))
    fc = tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(bottom, W), b)
    return fc

pts = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,2], name="p")
label = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None], name="labels")

with tf.variable_scope("layers") as scope:
    fc1 = fc_layer(pts, [2, 6], "fc1")
    fc1 = tf.nn.tanh(fc1)
    fc2 = fc_layer(fc1, [6, 2], "fc2")
    fc2 = tf.nn.tanh(fc2)
cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(fc2, label, name='cross_entropy_per_example')
cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy, name='cross_entropy')
optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate, momentum)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy_mean, global_step=global_step)
###

ce_summary = tf.scalar_summary('ce', cross_entropy_mean)

with tf.Session() as session:
    all_summaries = tf.merge_all_summaries()
    summarizer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('./log', session.graph)
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    for i in range(len(points) // batch_size):
        _, ce, cs = session.run([
            train_op,
            cross_entropy_mean,
            ce_summary
        ],
        {
            pts: points[i:(i + batch_size)],
            label: labels[i:(i + batch_size)]
        })
        summarizer.add_summary(cs, global_step=tf.train.global_step(session, global_step))
        print(ce)
```

It does not seem yet the best the network can do, but the cross-entropy does diminish!

Comment: Thanks for your kindness and nice sample code!! I also realized that the problem was about "initialization". I simply changed it to truncated_random thing with default parameter. I guess yours can be better. Some people may also want to see https://github.com/ywpkwon/tf_toy_2d_classification. Thanks again! :)

Comment: There is also the bit on batch size. Changing it does influence the speed and convergence. Glad the post confirms your findings.